# Foundation SASS amending button-radius

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

So I've recently set-up a new project using Zurb's Foundation. I've got the default setting working from the gem setup (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html).

**The problem I am having is amending the buttons.** By default my buttons appear square & I want a nice rounded corner style. So within the `_settings.scss` I have amended the following line:

```
$button-radius: 30px;
```

But nothing happens. So after reading the documentation I tried creating my own button class and including the **button mixin** like so:

```
.your-class-name {
    @include button($padding, $bg, $radius, $full-width, $disabled, $is-input);
}
```

But when I do this I get an error saying that `$padding` doesn't exist! This has royally confused me as it's used throughout Foundation (or so I understand).

Can anyone suggest what may be going wrong here. I can provide any additional information if need be.

Lastly, I don't think the `$global-radius` option is being applied, because when I change the property but it's not causing an error so I'm a little stumped!

EDIT:

Here is the top of my core SASS file:

```
// Global Foundation Settings
@import "settings";

// Comment out this import if you don't want to use normalize
@import "normalize";

// Comment out this import if you are customizing you imports below
@import "foundation";
```

Comment: `$padding` is the name of the argument for that mixin, you have to pass it a value, not a variable that hasn't been initialized.  Is the settings file being included ahead of all of your other includes?

Comment: I see. But am I correct in thinking that it should be initialized within the default Foundation file?

Comment: I've added the top of the file which shows the imports (which includes the Settings at the top of the page)

Comment: No.  [Global variables](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_variables.scss) in Foundation are prefixed in someway, leaving the authors free to use shorter named variables within mixins (avoiding having mixins accidentally overwriting global variables).  If you look at the [button mixin](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss), you can see that it defaults to using `$button-med` for padding.

Comment: I see! Thanks :) Okay seem to have it working by my own class. Still interested to know why the default `$border-radius` doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Looking at the code, it *should* work the way you're expecting.  Though it's possible that variable could be overwritten somewhere by accident.  Try adding `@debug $button-radius;` after your foundation import.

Answer (score 0):

The default `$border-radius` did not work due to a bug in Foundation. I ran into it as well, but when I now went to double-check, it appears to have been fixed already in [this commit](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/commit/f98b9a7dbe798c318c912cada854b95dcdd462e0). The problem was that `$button-radius` was defined twice in the settings file, one for buttons in general, and one for buttons in forms. The latter has now been renamed to `$form-button-radius`.